# Database Read Error, Classic ASP

Tags: sql-server, vbscript, asp-classic, adodb

When connecting to my database, I'm getting a error code of 500 from my server which references me to [THIS LINK](http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/running-classic-asp-applications-on-iis-7-and-iis-8), but I know the asp is enabled on our server because the code executes fine until it gets to the line executing  `Recordset.Open SQL,Connection.` To ensure I'm establishing a successful database connection, I write a message stating "Connected OK" which works fine until the Recordset.Open statement is added (tested by removing Recordset and it works fine). The ASP file is being called via a AJAX request in my React.JS app which sits in a HTML module on DotNetNuke, and that works no problem as well. Our servers are running IIS 8 with SQL Server 2008 installed.

Update - Error Code From Server:

```
Conversion_failed_when_converting_the_varchar_value_'2520-031'_to_data_type_int. 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.3;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/50.0.2661.94+Safari/537.36 http://localhost/Test.aspx 500 0 0 24
```

Edit: I know my SQL statement saying "table" is wrong, I just didn't feel comfortable posting the actual table name on here.

Any suggestions to improve this code are welcomed to (or an example using ASP.Net as well).

ASP Code:

```vb
<%

line = request.querystring("q")
Response.Write("Hello" & line)

Dim conn
Dim Recordset
DIM SQL 

SQL = "SELECT * from table"

Set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set Recordset = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

conn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source = ****; Initial Catalog = ****; User Id = ****; Password= ****"
Recordset.Open SQL,Connection

If conn.errors.count = 0 Then

    Response.Write "Connected OK"

End If

conn.close

%>
```

Comment: Random Downvote explain why

Comment: Do you know the difference between ASP.Net and Classic ASP? You can't just use an amalgamation of the two and expect it to work. At the moment the file you are testing has a `.aspx` extension which means on any IIS web server the processing of the file will be being handled by the ASP.Net Handler not the Classic ASP Engine. You also need to think about sorting out your error handling so you get meaningful errors returned from ASP/IIS.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
Recordset.Open SQL,conn
```

rather than

```
Recordset.Open SQL,Connection
```

Comment: Can you please explain why.

Comment: You have to pass your connection object (conn) where you have the connection string specified. What you are doing is passing a Connection class, which is not what that parameter excepts. See this http://www.w3schools.com/asp/met_rs_open.asp

Comment: Can you paste the exact error message in your question?

Comment: 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: An error occurred on the server when processing the URL. Please contact the system administrator. <p/> If you are the system administrator please click <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=82731">here</a> to find out more about this error.

Comment: Ok, check the event log of the machine where this application is hosted. Usually the 500 error has a decimal point which indicates exact server error. Do you see anything like that?

Comment: Ok, I will have to do that in the morning because I dont have access to that machine at the moment. Any clue as to why this would be happening ?

Comment: If it's coming from the "Recordset.Open SQL,Connection" line then the server where you hosted the application may not have connectivity to the database you specified in the connection string. Could be a security/ permission issue. Event log will give you the details. And, there's another place where you could see for error logs. I.e. IIS logs located in C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles But, you have to find the correct log based on the worker process id. You can find out the worker process id by going to IIS website's Advanced Settings. The ID field indicates the Worker process ID.

Comment: But if it didn't have access, wouldn't i get an error when I'm checking to see if I'm establishing a connection. The app is on my localhost now, and the DB is on our live server. Maybe it's rejecting the localhost origin ?

Comment: Ok, best way to test that is use the user id and password and login through SQL Server management Studio. If you can't that means you can't connect from the application as well.

Comment: Well, what I did to verify the password and username was correct was I purposely entered the wrong info and I got denied. And when entering the correct info, it came back valid and I got my "OK connection" print out. Does that verify In the same sense you're explaining ?

Comment: Yeah that's also fine. Then you need to dig deeper. Have a look at these posts. http://forums.iis.net/t/1181073.aspx?classic+asp+and+internal+server+error+500+help+required+   http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1369811-20-1.aspx

Comment: Conversion_failed_when_converting_the_varchar_value_'2520-031'_to_data_type_int. 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.3;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/50.0.2661.94+Safari/537.36 http://localhost/Test.aspx 500 0 0 24

Comment: Your error message suggests that this is happening on a file called `test.aspx`.  Unless you have set up some very unorthodox file associations in IIS manager the aspx extension is for asp.net - try renaming your file `test.asp`

Comment: Hey guys, I ended up figuring out the issue was my SQL query string. I didn't add quotes around a specific section of my query as expected.